# react native geocoding get address

Tags: react-native, reverse-geocoding

I need help for this kind of error when running this will happen object [] , []

```
Geocoder.getFromLatLng(28.6139,77.2090).then(
  json => {
        var addressComponent = json.results[0].address_components[0];
        alert(addressComponent);
    }, error => {
      alert(error+"CATCH");
    } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to `alert` an object doing so usually results in getting the following response:

[object Object]

[image: Alert]

Which isn't really useful. You can solve this by using `JSON.stringify`

`alert(JSON.stringify(addressComponent))` or `alert(JSON.stringify(error))`

Doing a reverse geocode lookup on the coordinates gives the following alert when I use `JSON.stringify`

[image: geocode lookup]

You can read more about `JSON.stringify` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) in the docs.

> The `JSON.stringify()` method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string

While using `alert` is useful, I prefer using `console.warn` as you would get something like this, which means you don't have to `stringify` every response

[image]

Comment: hmmm this solve my problem thank you Andrew I just need to JSON.stringify